# Spring batch chunk on nested object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am using spring batch to read the xml file below with `StaxEventItemReader`

sample of the xml file:

```
<ArrayOfStoreTransaction CustomerID="C1">
    <PurchaseHistory Type="purchase.001" Count="2">
        <StoreTransaction>
            <CustomerID>C1</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>C1A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
        <StoreTransaction>
            <CustomerID>C1</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>C1A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
    </PurchaseHistory>
    <PurchaseHistory Type="purchase.002" Count="1">
        <StoreTransaction>
            <CustomerID>S3</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>S3A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
    </PurchaseHistory>
    <PurchaseHistory Type="purchase.003" Count="2">
        <StoreTransaction>
            <CustomerID>S3</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>S3A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
        <StoreTransaction>
            <CustomerID>S3</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>S3A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
    </PurchaseHistory>
</ArrayOfStoreTransaction>
```

this is also my objects for binding the xml

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "PurchaseHistory")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Data
public class PurchaseHistoryList {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Type")
    private String type;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Count")
    private int count;

    @XmlElement(name = "StoreTransaction")
    private List<StoreTransaction> storeTransactions;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Data
class StoreTransaction {

    @XmlElement(name = "CustomerID")
    private String customerID;

    @XmlElement(name = "CustomerAccount")
    private String customerAccount;
}
```

this is my Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Step reportStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                             PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager,
                                             ItemStreamReader<PurchaseHistoryList> reportItemReader,
                                             ItemWriter<PurchaseHistoryList> reportItemWriter,
                                             @Value("${chunk.size}") Integer chunkSize) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("reportStep")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .<PurchaseHistoryList, PurchaseHistoryList>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(reportItemReader)
                .writer(reportItemWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job reportJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                                           JobRepository jobRepository,
                                           Step reportStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("reportJob")
                .repository(jobRepository)
                .start(reportStep)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Unmarshaller paymentUnmarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(PurchaseHistoryList.class);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemStreamReader<PurchaseHistoryList> reportItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[filePath]}") String filePath) {
        StaxEventItemReader<PurchaseHistoryList> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(filePath));
        reader.setFragmentRootElementName("PurchaseHistory");
        reader.setUnmarshaller(paymentUnmarshaller());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<PurchaseHistoryList> reportItemWriter(PurchaseHistoryListRepository repository) {
        return new PurchaseHistoryListWriter(repository);
    }
}
```

What I want is to apply the chunk on the list of StoreTransaction objects. For example, if the chunk size is set to 1, each PurchaseHistoryList provided to the writer should contain only one StoreTransaction object in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. You defined one item as a `PurchaseHistory` XML element, which might contain one or more `StoreTransaction` elements.

The chunk size is applied to the outer item (not nested ones).

Comment: is there any workaround to apply the chunk on the StoreTransaction elements but at the same time got the right value of the "Type" attribute for each  StoreTransaction ?

Comment: No. I think the code you shared is correct. What is the problem? Why are you looking to have the chunk size applied to `StoreTransaction`? Can you explain what you are trying to achieve without referring to Spring Batch?

Comment: I am trying to save the StoreTransaction elements as entities inside the database
the number of StoreTransaction elements will be very huge and the number of  PurchaseHistory elements will be small that's why I want the chunk size to be applied on StoreTransaction not on the PurchaseHistory 
Also I need the value of the Type attribute of the PurchaseHistory inside every StoreTransaction entity

Comment: I see. I don't think you can do this in one go with the provided reader. You would either prepare the file in a prior step by setting the purchase type on every  `StoreTransaction`, or use a custom reader that returns nested elements with the type set on them.